# Apps link in iTunes Connect stop working after 2021 WWDC

Tags: app-store-connect

The "Apps" link in the new iTunes Connection landing page does not work. Clicking on it has no response at all. Checking the browser console and it is showing a 401 error, "the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)".

Tried to clean the cache and also tried in the incognito mode however the error persists.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a re-direction from the Developer Dashboard does the trick.

Try this URL, https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps

[image]